# Simulate click on GitHub's newsfeed "More" button in JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, greasemonkey

I'm trying to create a GreaseMonkey script that automatically extends the list of alerts in GitHub's newsfeed but that doesn't work.

Here is my code (inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379507/clicking-a-link-with-greasemonkey-from-the-content-inside-link) post):

```
var moreLink = $("a:contains('More')");
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initEvent("click", true, true);
moreLink[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
```

But instead of expending the list of alerts like it does when you manually click on it, it just opens the page the link points too (`https://github.com/organizations/my_organization?page=2`)

How can I do this?

Edit:
Here is the HTML source code of the link, it looks like there is no javascript or onClick event associated to it:

```
<a href="/organizations/my_organization?page=2">More</a>
```

Edit 2:
Here is my full greasemonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @namespace   test
// @description test
// @include     https://github.com
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

var moreLink = $("#dashboard div.news div.pagination a:contains('More')");
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initEvent("click", true, true);
moreLink[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
//alert($(".alert").length);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "GitHub's newsfeed".  Link to a specific page or RSS feed.  Do you need to be signed in to see it?

Comment: Yes, you need to be signed in to see it. It is the page you see at `https://github.com` when you're signed in with the list of all the most recent updates on the repos you're watching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly for me -- on the main page, when logged in. Though I would recommend that you use a more specific selector, to avoid false positives.

EG, use:

```
var moreLink = $("#dashboard div.news div.pagination a:contains('More')");
```

---

- What version of Firefox and Greasemonkey are you using?
- Is NoScript, Adblock, or similar running?
- You say that it looks like there is no javascript or onClick event associated with the link... How did you check?  Firebug shows several event-listeners on that node.
- What errors appear in Firefox's error console (<kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), besides the zillions of CSS warnings that GitHub generates?
- Is your script doing anything else to the page?  Especially adding or deleting content or using `innerHTML`?  If so, post or link to the full script.

---

### Update for new information:

1. On further testing, from more environments, it now appears as if GitHub's pagination is not always initialized by the time the Greasemonkey script fires. To get around that, use [the waitForKeyElements() utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891) and check for pagination-engine readiness before attempting to click the link.  See below.
2. Greasemonkey 0.9.19 was buggy as all get-out -- hence it was only active for a few days.
   Go to [the Greasemonkey Version History page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/versions/) and **install either version 0.9.20 or version 0.9.18.**
3. The `@include` directive may not be firing when you want it.  It needs to be at least:

   ```
   // @include https://github.com/
   ```

   But

   ```
   // @include https://github.com/*
   ```

   might be better, and the selector is specific enough that a broader include should cause no harm.
4. Step up to jQuery version 1.7.2 -- we've used it extensively with no problems.  (1.5.1 is probably not the problem, but best to eliminate that variable.)

Putting all that together, the following script works for me, from a variety of (Windows) environments. I left most of the debugging code in, just in case...

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _GitHub "news" item auto-paging
// @namespace   _pc
// @include     https://github.com/
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// ==/UserScript==

if (typeof unsafeWindow.console.clear != 'undefined') {
    unsafeWindow.console.clear ();
}
unsafeWindow.console.log ("Start...");  //-- Does not require Firebug.

waitForKeyElements (
    "#dashboard div.news div.pagination a:contains('More')",
    clickAjaxMoreLink,
    true    //-- Stop on first successful click.
);

function clickAjaxMoreLink (jNode) {
    this.numRuns    = this.numRuns || 1;

    unsafeWindow.console.log (
        "moreLink:", jNode,
        " | Parent classes:", jNode.parent ().attr ("class"),
        " | Run:", this.numRuns
    );
    this.numRuns++;
    /*--- COMMENT THIS NEXT CHECK OUT, if waitForKeyElements is set to
        continually click via clickAjaxMoreLink. (The last param is false.)
    */
    if (this.numRuns > 25) {
        unsafeWindow.console.log ("*** Excessive runcount, abort! ***");
        return false;
    }

    if (jNode.parent ().hasClass ("loading") ) {
        return true;    //-- Cancel the "found" status.
    }
    var unsfJQ_Body = unsafeWindow.$(document.body);
    if (    ! unsfJQ_Body
        ||  ! unsfJQ_Body.length
        ||  document.readyState != "complete"   //-- Order is important here
        ||  (typeof unsfJQ_Body.pageUpdate) != "function"
    ) {
        return true;
    }

    unsafeWindow.console.log ("Num news items, start:", $(".alert").length);

    setTimeout ( function () {
        unsafeWindow.console.log (
            "Num news items, after AJAX delay:", $(".alert").length
        );
    }, 2333);

    var evt = document.createEvent ("MouseEvents");
    evt.initEvent ("click", true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);

    return false;
}

unsafeWindow.console.log ("Setup complete...");
```

Comment: I updated the original post with the full script. I am running Firefox 12 with Greasemonkey 0.9.19. There are no errors appearing in Firefox's console, just the CSS warnings. When I run this script, it is just loading `https://github.com/dashboard/index/2` (which is the exact same page)

Comment: Okay, see the updated answer -- which accounts for race conditions and AJAX delays (in my tests anyway).

Comment: Thank you for your help, that was the problem! I have one more question though: How can I access the new div elements that were added? `$("#dashboard div.news div.alert").length` still returns 30 even after the click

Comment: Please disregard my previous question, I was running into the same problem... (data was not loaded yet). Thanks for your help.